# MEAN Stack, How do call a method in server controller from client controller

Tags: mean-stack

Using the MEAN.JS stack with yo generator.

In terminal I created a new module `yo meanjs:crud-module scraper`. This all works fine but I would like to modify it a little.

In `scrapers.server.controller.js` I would like to add a custom method that can be called from `scrapers.client.controller.js`

I copied an existing method and renamed it to `exports.scrape = function(req, res) { };`

How can I call this from `scrapers.client.controller.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time of understanding how this server side MVC and client side MVC all work together in one stack. Through more research and reading, the following is what I found:

I think the way it works is the server controller communicate with client controller through RESTful API.

Such as, you define your custom method in the server controller, and you call your function in your server side controller, save the return value, then JSON() it to res. You don't directly call that method to the client controller (i don't think it's even possible...).

Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks, and happy MEANing.